# find_or_initialize_by non-unique attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have an InventoryItem model as follows:

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to  :item, :foreign_key => :code, :primary_key => :code
    belongs_to  :vendor
    has_many    :list_items
    has_many    :shopping_lists, through: :list_items

    def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        InventoryItem.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

I want to modify the self.import method so that I can upload a csv file and it will find_or_initialize. In this way I can update an inventory without having to delete it and repopulate it every time a price changes. My issue is that I can't find_by the primary `:id` attribute because the incoming CSV file has no knowledge of these id's. Here is my table schema for InventoryItem:

```
class InventoryItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :inventory_items do |t|
        t.decimal :price
        t.integer :vendor_id
        t.integer :code, :limit => 8
    end

    add_index :inventory_items, [:code, :vendor_id]
  end
end
```

`:code` is not unique, as many other vendors have the same product with the same code. Is there some way to find_or_initialize_by both code and vendor_id? Do you see any other workaround for what I'm trying to do? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Okay so I have a method that now looks like this:

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        my_object = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_vendor_id(code, vendor_id)
        my_object.update_attributes(row.to_hash)
    end
end
```

But how do I pass in each code and vendor_id to the find_or_initialize_by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_vendor_id(code, vendor_id)
```

Comment: Ah okay glad to see this is fairly straightforward. Thank you. One question though, how do I pass in each `code` and `vendor_id` to the find_or_initialize method when this is coming from a CSV file? I'll update my question with my modified method.

Comment: Assuming you know which column each of those fields will be in you can just do `InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_vendor_id(row[0], row[1])`

Comment: So you would specify row instead of column?

Comment: ya right row[0] or row[1] where your code and vendor_id comes